# SSRS - possible to share the same filter definition for a chart and a tablix?

Tags: reporting-services

In Excel you have the option of showing a table below your chart that shows the data used in the chart - I am trying to replicate that behavior in SSRS.

Scenario:
I have one dataset from which I want to populate two (Chart + Table) elements (so two charts and two tables).  Each Chart + Table combo needs to use the exact same filter, but I don't want to manually define that exact same filter on each object (if I need to change it,  I don't want to have to make the change on two entities).

Yes I know there are other ways to accomplish the same end result, such as perform the filter in the SQL, or to instead define two separate datasets, and then apply the filter on the dataset itself (so it will then cascade down to both the Chart and Table).....or in other words, I'm not asking if this is a *good idea*, I'm asking if it is *possible*.  :)

Comment: Interesting question. I have never tried it, but I wonder if this is possible with custom code in the report (Report Properties->Code). It's central to the report, and you could apply the filter once, and make future changes in one place.

Comment: @R.Richards Maybe this:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbc305ea-e9b7-420d-98bf-773fafbedf39/can-we-use-two-filter-in-ssrs-under-or-condition?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: That is basically what I was thinking. But, I would avoid a function with parameters in case those need to change in the future. If the function could return what you need without having to pass something into it, you can avoid having to changing things in more than one place later on down the road. Theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I can think of to what you want is to define the logic of your filter in custom code, and call the custom code in your two filters.

If the logic ever changes, you would only have to change it in one place.

But it's not possible to define the filter on your tablix, for instance, and then in your chart put in some kind of "use the same filter as my tablix" command.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a **Calculated Field** that checks your criteria and gives a 1 or 0 depending on whether it meets all the criteria or not.

> Field Name: MeetCriteria

```
=IIF(Fields!AGE.Value < 10 and Fields!status.Value = "PAID", 1, 0)
```

Then you just need to filter on the new calculated column:

```
Expression: Fields!MeetCriteria.Value
Type: INTEGER
Operator: = 
Value: 1
```

Not quite what you want but much easier than duplicating the criteria everywhere.

For a multi-value Status parameter, you could do something like:

```
=IIF(Fields!AGE.Value < 10 
  AND INSTR("|" & Join(Parameters!Status.Value, "|") & "|", "|" & Fields!Status.Value & "|") > 0, 
  1, 0)
```

Comment: And this could reference parameters instead of hardcoded values right?  What about multi-select parameters, could it handle that?

Comment: You could substitute parameters but multi-value parameters would be a little tougher since expressions aren't meant to work on sets. Maybe something like: `...AND INSTR("|" & Join(Parameters!Status.Value, "|") & "|", "|" & Fields!Status.Value & "|") > 0`. This looks for the Status field in the Status parameter values. The pipes ( | ) are used to ensure that you don't get **PAID** when one of the parameter values is **UNPAID**.